# ¿Como corrijo el look and feel por defecto desde el main, java netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas tardes compañeros,

Actualmente tengo el ultimo inconveniente con mi software de proyecto y gracias al cielo no es más que estetico.

Estoy haciendo el proyecto con MVC y pues ya tengo todas las vistas con el look and feel "nimbus", a continuación les muestro el login.

[image: Login estilo nimbus]

Pero hago el llamado desde el main mediante el siguiente código

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vista_Login VistaL = new Vista_Login();
        Modelo_AdministradorDAO ModeloAdminDAO = new Modelo_AdministradorDAO();
        Modelo_MedicoDAO ModeloMedDAO= new Modelo_MedicoDAO();
        Modelo_PacienteDAO ModeloPacDAO= new Modelo_PacienteDAO();
        Controlador_Login ControladorL = new Controlador_Login(VistaL, ModeloAdminDAO, ModeloMedDAO, ModeloPacDAO);
        ControladorL.InicializarLogin();
    }
```

El ControladorL.InicializarLogin(); contiene lo siguiente:

```java
public void InicializarLogin (){
        VistaLog.setVisible(true);
        VistaLog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
```

Así que por lo que ven, no es nada del otro mundo.

Pero al momento de ejecutar el main, el login pierde el estilo nimbus y aparece el de windows, así:

[image: Login estilo windows]

Lo que me deja con la intriga de como corregirlo. La vista no tiene nada de código, solo tiene los componentes.

**¿Como logro que se ejecute y persista el estilo nimbus durante la ejecución del programa?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `main()` lo primero que deberías hacer es setear el LAF con el método `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
    Vista_Login VistaL = new Vista_Login();
```

Sólo hay que hacerlo una vez y es recomendable hacerlo al inicio por que a partir de ahí todos los Componentes UI utilizarán el LAF especificado.

Comment: Y exactamente en qué punto lo debo colocar del main? O lo debo poner en todas las vistas? En que parte?

Comment: Al principio, antes de instanciar cualquier vista.

Comment: Cabe añadir, que despúes toca hacer los imports correspondientes!